# How to go back to default styles / theme when using jQuery addClass/removeClass?

Tags: jquery, css, addclass, removeclass

I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UxVF9/

```
$('#theme1').click(function() {
    $('.links a').removeClass().addClass('theme1');
});
```

How can I go back to the default colorful state (theme1) by pressing the "Theme 1"-button?

I know that I remove all classes with "removeClass()" and I've tried a lot, but still, this is making me crazy.

I appreciate help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store all the initial themes in an array.  [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UxVF9/4/)

```
var initial = new Array (); //empty array
$('.links a').each(function(index) { //each element in the selector is returned in the same order and has an index.
    initial[index] = $(this).attr('class'); // add the starting class to the empty array positioned with the index
});
$('#theme1').click(function() {
    $('.links a').removeClass().each(function(index) { //same order and index 
        $(this).addClass(initial[index]); // add the classes back using the array and index
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, I have to learn a lot more before fully understanding this. Why double hashtag? A typo? (##theme1).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is just to remove the classes that you don't need.

```
$('#theme1').click(function() {
    $('.links a').removeClass("theme2 theme3").addClass('theme1');
});
```

However, this is not sufficient because the specific classes have priority and work properly with theme1.  You need to increase the specificity of theme2 and theme3, but this is pretty simple:

```
.links .theme2 { background-color: #000; color: #fff; text-decoration:none; }
```

Place this *after* the other rulesets in the CSS.

---

You can also make this simpler/more flexible by removing all classes that begin with "theme" functionally and also using a single class to bind: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/UxVF9/2/